# geom_bar change color in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a `bar plot` via `ggplot2` in `R` using the code below, how can I change the inside color of the bars when only `one` column is being used in `aes`? Please note that the data frame does not have a column named `count`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_frame, aes(x = class.1_value)) + 
  geom_bar(color ="steelblue") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fill ="steelblue"` instead of `color ="steelblue"`